# LocalSessionFactoryBean is returning null SessionFactory Object Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-orm

```
@Bean //<bean class="HibernateTemplate" name="getHibernateTemplate">
public HibernateTemplate getHibernateTemplate() {
    HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate();
    LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    localSessionFactoryBean.setAnnotatedPackages("com.harish.spring.orm.entity");
    localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(getDataSource());
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect");
    localSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(p);
    hibernateTemplate.setSessionFactory(localSessionFactoryBean.getObject()); //this returns null
    return hibernateTemplate;
}
```

```
 SessionFactory object that it returns is null.
```

in the above code I am setting up LocalSessionFactoryBean and it's all requried properties. the SessionFactory object that it returns is null.